# Extracting part of a string in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I need to extract part of the string that is after '-' part of the string.

lets say,

> LONGNAME Andrew-stellar Alex-COOK

Expected output:

> COOK stellar

I tried with:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(LONGNAME,'(-.*)',1) as shortname
```

But it gives:

> -COOK
>   -Stellar

how can i remove '-'?

Answer (score 0):

try adding [REPLACE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#replace) function also:

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage() AS (longname:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(REGEX_EXTRACT(longname,'(-.*)',1),'-','') as shortname;

DUMP B;
```

output:

> (stellar) (COOK)